# Sharing my HashiCorp Vault secret with a named user

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have created a secret in HashiCorp Vault which I would like to share with my colleague.  Please let me know the best way to accomplish the sharing of secret using HashiCorp Vault.  Something similar to how Google Drive allows you to share a document with named colleague email ids.

One of the ways to accomplish this is to create a policy ("sys/policies/*") and attach it to my colleague's entity.  However, I would end up seeing policies created by root user and other colleagues which is not advisable.

I am not able to find a way to create and manage policy which is viewable only by me and no one else.  At the moment, I am able to see policies created by everyone else including root when I use "sys/policies/*".

If I am able to create and manage policies created by only me, then I would create a policy to share the secret with my colleague only.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will require Vault ACL policy path templating. The guide at the link below will provide more details.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/policy-templating

In short, you can template one's identity entity, identity entity alias, or identity group attributes into your policies. When your colleague attempts to view the secrets or policies, if you've configured your policy to template his name or group name into the path, then he should only be able to see the secret or policy based on that.